# Change Git Directory Setup VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My projects is on a networked drive T.

When I do a command such as:

```
git add path/to/file.ext
```

The file gets staged just fine.

However when I use the UI in Visual Studio code and look at the output on the same file it does this:

```
git add -A -- t:\path\to\file.ext
```

And there is an error:

```
Git: fatal: t:\path\to\file.ext: 't:\path\to\file.ext' is outside repository.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. When I stage and commit and all that via Tortise GIT no problem. I'm not sure what the problem is. I guess is has to be with the IDE, but what? I tested doing the manual entries and I've found it's when the `T:\` is added, but how do I fix that. What am I to do to remove the drive name.

Comment: Are you sure is not the problem of git setting in VS .

Comment: Could be. Basically I clone and create everything via Tortise GIT in Windows. Then just open the folder with VS. I didn't init/config anything in VS. All my other repos work just fine. This is the only one that does this. I don't even see where/how to config GIT in VS.

Comment: the file you are adding, do you see it in the explorer on VS Code ?

Comment: Did you found a fix for this issue? I'm experiencing this also. VSCode version 1.48.2. It seems that this is a fixed issue in the VSCode github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89373. But here its in the current version still a bug.

Comment: This was a while ago, but if I remember right, this was a bug on my part. I had changed the repository names in bitbucket, but didn't update in my local files. I believe after I updated the remote path it fixed it.